# Scrolling to an id with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to scroll to an element with a specific id and a specific class. For example a simple script for smooth scrolling to a specific id is

```
$(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
        var $target = $(this.hash);
        $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});
        return false;
     });
});
```

This is useful if you have something like

```
<div id="space-red"></div>
<div id="space-blue"></div>
<div id="space-green"></div>
```

However if you have a page such as

```
<div id="space-red" class="class1"></div>
<div id="space-blue" class="class1"></div>
<div id="space-red" class="class2"></div>
<div id="space-blue" class="class2"></div>
<div id="space-green" class="class1"></div>
```

Would you be able to navigate between the two `space-red` or `space-blue` ids by differentiating between the classes they have assigned to them?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Why not? This is how most of portfolio pages work. Unique ID

Comment: I don't think it is... you can't have multiple IDs on the same page. `getElementById` returns **one** item for a reason. Instead, just use multiple classes.

Comment: Element ID's should be unique within the entire document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme

Comment: You could get all elements with the `class1` class and then use the IDs to differentiate them, but why do this? Isn't using the ID in the first place different enough?

Comment: @RanchiRhino Element IDs should be unique BUT HTML will still work even if they aren't unique and jQuery will return an array instead of a single item

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/8tLdq/1/

Comment: @SylvanDAsh jquery will also only return one item when using `$('#id')` : https://jsfiddle.net/gkp7w9s4/

Comment: The above jsfiddle prints out 5 times though...but from my experience with jQuery on Chrome & Firefox, it will return an array if you have more than 1 element with the same ID

Answer (score 1):

Ids must be unique, try change `id` to `data-id`, here is an example:

```js
var target = $('div[data-id="space-red"].class2').offset().top;

console.log(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="space-red" class="class1"></div>
<div data-id="space-blue" class="class1"></div>
<div data-id="space-red" class="class2"></div>
<div data-id="space-blue" class="class2"></div>
<div data-id="space-green" class="class1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the **classes** as if they were **IDs** and **IDs** as if they were **classes**. The IDs are unique for the entire document and therefore should only be one.

You need to think the other way round and logic will correctly.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, Ids **must** be unique, but you can use class to control and select element or other attribute.
In this way, select the element with the class not flagged, and add a flag on end. Something like:

```
$(function () {
 $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
    var $target = $(this.hash + ':not(.flag)');
    $target = $target.length ? $target : $('html');
    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, {duration: 1500, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'});

    $('.flag').removeClass('flag');
    $target.addClass('flag');


    return false;
 });});
```